# Late Binding Global Variables?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using VBA for Excel.  From my understanding, global variables need to be declared outside of any subs.  That's the only way they can be accessed by all subs.

At the meantime, I want to do late binding to reference the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library(in order to use the dictionary object type) so that an end user doesn't have to do it himself.

My code is as below:

```
On Error Resume Next
strGUID = "{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}"
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid GUID:=strGUID, Major:=1, Minor:=0

Dim Dic1 As Object
Set Dic1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim Dic2 As Object
Set Dic2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

What if I want to declare global dictionary object with late binding?  It looks like VBA won't allow me to put any code outside of the subs (other than the declarations).

How may I declare a global dictionary object without needing the end user configure library reference himself?  Shall I don the following?

```
Dim Dic1 As Object
Dim Dic2 As Object

Sub Prog1()
    On Error Resume Next
    strGUID = "{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}"
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid GUID:=strGUID, Major:=1, Minor:=0

    Set Dic1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set Dic2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub
```

Comment: You can only declare the object, not set it. So just `Dim Dic1 As Object` outside of the sub. Perhaps in Workbook_Open() sub/event you can do the Set?

Comment: Side note: while scanning your code I see `On Error Resume Next` with no `On Error GoTo` anywhere to turn it off. This is very dangerous - you'll never know when your code throws an error, nor what caused it.

Comment: Why do you need to make a reference if you're going to be using `CreateObject()` and late binding instead of `New`?

Comment: FWIW you very rarely *need* a global variable. You know how to pass parameters to procedures/functions?

Comment: Also the Scripting Runtime library is standard issue on every single Windows box, and hasn't seen an update this century, and is unlikely to see one in the foreseeable future - unless your code needs to run on a Mac, there's no need to late-bind that library. Project references are saved along with the VBA project in the host document, users don't need to add them themselves.

Comment: Mathieu, from my understanding the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library is not referenced by default.  We either have to configure Excel to include it.  Or use code to reference it.  Was that not right?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, *you* (the developer) need to add it. **Once**. Once it's there, it's there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like the VBA code itself, project references don't magically disappear when your user opens your host workbook. They're saved along with the code in the host document.

So, the premise of your question is wrong: users never need to tweak project references.

Also the Scripting Runtime type library is standard issue and has been shipped the exact same version on every single Windows machine built this century (even before that), which means unless your code needs to run on a Mac, there's no need to ever late-bind the Scripting Runtime library.

And if your code needs to run on a Mac, the library won't late-bind anyway because it won't be found on the host machine, so late-binding the Scripting Runtime only serves to make silly typos and introduce other easily avoidable bugs that *IntelliSense* helps preventing.

---

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid GUID:=strGUID, Major:=1, Minor:=0
```

This defeats the entire purpose of late-binding: it's using the VBIDE extensibility library (which requires lowered macro security settings) to programmatically add a reference that you can easily add at design-time through the VBE's **Tools** menu.

Late-bound code doesn't need the reference at all. Not at compile-time, not at run-time.

Add the reference, save, then declare your objects `As Scripting.Dictionary` and enjoy the benefits of early-bound code.

```
Set Dic1 = New Scripting.Dictionary
```

That's all you need.

---

> What if I want to declare global dictionary object with late binding? It looks like VBA won't allow me to put any code outside of the subs (other than the declarations).

Late binding isn't any different than early binding in that aspect. The **only** difference between late and early bound code is the `As` clause of the declaration:

```
Private foo As Object ' no compile-time type knowledge: late-bound
Private bar As Dictionary ' compile-time type knowledge: early-bound
```

How you're initializing that object reference makes no difference to the late/early binding nature of the declaration.

This looks up a ProgID in the registry to find the library and the type:

```
Set foo = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

This uses the project references:

```
Set foo = New Scripting.Dictionary
```

Both are correct, and both will work against either early or late-bound declarations. Except, if you already have a reference to the type library, there's not really a need to go hit the registry to locate that library - just `New` it up!

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are really not needed and should be avoided. However, if you have decided to use them for a your own reasons, you can put them in the `Workbook_Open` event:

```
Option Explicit

Dim Dic1 As Object
Dim Dic2 As Object

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Set Dic1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set Dic2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

End Sub
```

Thus, it would create the object every time the workbook is opened.

Comment: Gah, I got side-tracked with the early/late binding thing, and forgot to address the actual initialization of the variables - upvoted.