# VBA Dictionary Run Time Error 1004

Tags: vba, dictionary

I am trying to sort rows based on names and put them in their own worksheets. I am using a Dictionary in order to keep track of the current row for each. I have included a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime. Every time I run, it gets to the line indicated in the code and then throws a Run-Time Error 1004, Application-defined or object defined error. In addition, when I watch `nameDict` The value is: `<Object variable or With block variable not set>` however the type is `Dictionary`. Is this because it's not being initialized properly? I've read several different ways to initialize a dictionary and am confused on the best way. All other variables and functions work correctly as they've been tested independently and in other subs.

```
Private Sub sortTeamWork()
Dim nameDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim index As Integer
    index = getTargetColumn("Last Name")
    For i = CInt(getUsedRows()) To 2 Step -1
        name = Cells(i, index - 1) + " " + Cells(i, index)
        'The below line is where the error occurs
        If nameDict.Exists(name) Then
            nameDict.Items(name) = nameDict.Items(name) + 1
            Cells(i, index).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(name).Range("A" & nameDict(name))
        Else
            nameDict.Items(name) = 2
            Cells(i, index).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(name).Range("A" & nameDict(name))
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

There is a header on the worksheet I'm trying to copy the row to so it should start at row 2 and increment from there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Dim ... As New` can cause unexpected problems if you're not aware of all the implications. I can't fathom a reason for it to be `Nothing` with such code, but try splitting the declaration and the assignment into two instructions.

Comment: Same issue, `Dim nameDict As Variant
Set nameDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` is how I split it and it still had the 1004 error.

Comment: You have a reference to the scripting runtime, do `Dim nameDict As Scripting.Dictionary`, then `Set nameDict = New Scripting.Dictionary`. Don't introduce `Variant` there, you'll only lose intellisense and turn perfectly valid early-bound code into late-bound code for no reason. That said, are you *sure* the error is thrown on the line you think it is? `nameDict` being `Nothing` with `Dim...As New` is literally impossible, and would be throwing error 91, not 1004.

Comment: What's `getUsedRows` doing? Also consider using the `&` string concatenation operator instead of `+`, and try to work off an explicit worksheet object rather than implicitly off `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: `name`, a reserved word?  try using `sName` instead, I'm assuming it is meant to be a string.  To ensure the code is doing what you expect use an asserrtion, so `Debug.Assert TypeName(sName) = "String"` might shed light.

Comment: `getUsedRows` is determining the number of rows used, and I tried your suggestion and it looks like it fixed one problem, now it's at least acknowledging that it's an object but is still throwing the error. 

That being said, I found what was actually causing the error- I didn't declare `name`.

Comment: _Every time I run, it gets to the line indicated in the code_ Silly question: which line?

Answer (score -1):

You must either add reference by going to your `VBA project -> Tools -> References: Tick Microsoft Scripting Runtime.` and use Dictionary types

or
you can do a latebinding like

```
Dim nameDict As Object
set nameDict = createObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

make sure you have `Option Explicit` is set on top of the module. This will point out all compiler errors.

Comment: I have enabled Microsoft Scripting Runtime, which is why it's not throwing a type error.

Comment: A missing reference would be a compile-time error there. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354535/late-binding-global-variables/50355183#50355183) about late-binding the Scripting runtime library.