# Switch on references in locked VBA file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a VBA script in Word that requires multiple references such as MS Scripting Runtime and the Office and Object libraries. To prevent users from (accidentally) editing the code, I have locked the project. However this also prevents editing the References. Because the script is run on different computers, the references need to be switched on each time. 
Is it possible to embed activation of the libraries in the code? Or is there another way to prevent editing (reading is OK) of the code while still allowing the user to access the references menu?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the references of the standard libraries should stay with the file, whenever you are passing it around.

If you do not "trust" this, you have the following options:

1. Late binding - then you do not need references
2. Something as ugly as the code below + **late binding**
3. Something as ugly as the code below + start coding yourself with **early binding** (although I cannot think of a real scenario, when this would be preferred)

---

```
Sub TestMe
    On Error Resume Next
    strGUID = "{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}"
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid GUID:=strGUID, Major:=1, Minor:=0

    Dim Dic1 As Object
    Set Dic1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim Dic2 As Object
    Set Dic2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub
```

The code above comes from here - [Late Binding Global Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354535/late-binding-global-variables/50355296#50355296)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use early binding and set the references on the earliest platform you need to support. Your locked project should then run quite happily on PCs using later Win/Office versions.